# Программно растянуть модель STL

Tags: 3d, моделирование, stl-file

Условно сейчас есть модель "AAAAAАAAA". Её надо чем-то  разметить на "АААБББВВВ" и сделать из неё модели "АААББВВВ" и "АААБББББВВВ". (где А,Б,В это группы треугоников). Тоесть область А сохраняет геомертию, область Б растягивается-сжимается, область В перемещается с сохранением геометрии. Итог должен быть единым объектом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как программно это реализовать? Какой формат использовать чтоб сохранить метки группы точек? Какие программы помогут с этим?

Модель можно порезать на части вручную, но как их склеить обратно, чтоб было единое тело?

Comment: исходная модель в stl

Comment: stl внутри просто набор точек и треугольников (да, есть два формата stl). А после этого задача стает простой.

Comment: @KoVadim как склеить треугольники ?

Comment: метка stl значит совсем другое. как назвать новую метку для stl формате?)

Comment: Пускай будет STL-File )

Comment: @eri -  а их не нужно клеить. Просто нужно растянуть точки. Есть конечно вариант, что нужно будет треугольник разрезать (просто добавив точек)

Comment: C STL работать могу, но хочу `П= Паралепипед(xyz,xyz); А,Б,В= А.разрезать(П); Б=Б.scale(вектор); В=В.move(вектор); A = A+Б+В;`

Comment: Ну вот, у вас уже появился метод маркирования - плоскостями по осям (они уместнее параллелепипедов). Можете их хранить вне STL но рядом с ними?

Comment: @KoVadim разрезанные детали можно грузить в numpy и умножать на матрицы соответствующие

Comment: Ну так, что такое разрез - есть плоскость и нужно найти те треугольники, которые оно пересекает. Готово

Comment: надо бы что-то подекларативней)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего это можно сделать через скриптинг openscad

- union склеить
- translate передвинуть
- difference\intersection отрезать кусок

Пример «растянуть на 50»

```
module model () {
    import("model.stl");
}

module cutandpull (x) {
    union(){
        intersection(){ 
            model ();
            translate([-100,0,0]) cube([500,90,50]) ;
        }; //кусок А

        translate([0,90,0]) scale([1,(20+x)/20,1]) translate([0,-90,0]) intersection(){
            model ();
            translate([-100,90,0]) cube([500,20,50]) ;
        }; //кусок Б

        translate([0,x,0]) intersection(){
            model ();
            translate([-100,110,0]) cube([500,200,50]) ;
        }; //кусок В
    }
}

cutandpull (50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос слишком общий. В целом, это всё очень похоже на 9-tap sprites.

---

> Подскажите как программно это реализовать?

Загрузить модель, разметить, модифицировать геометрию, сохранить.

> Какой формат использовать чтоб сохранить метки группы точек?

Любой. От перечисления точек по индексам, до маркирования вершин и до задания ограничивающих диапазонов (объемов).

> Какие программы помогут с этим?

Готовых программ нету. Если вам нужно программное решение, то поможет та программа, которую вы сами напишете (с использованием библиотек загрузки/сохранения, например).

> Модель можно порезать на части вручную, но как их склеить обратно, чтоб было единое тело?

Если порежете на части, то потом так же их и склеите в формате (по совпадениям координат). Но лучше не резать, а маркировать.

Comment: программно - без участия человека на этапе местабирования

Comment: Любые - ну уж точно не любые) програмно управляемые.

Comment: Как маркировать в stl формате?

Comment: Если у вас ASCII формат, то например дописать в конец, после закрывающего тэга две плоскости по которым вы режете на части. Можете в файл рядом положить. Можете модифицировать вершины - в меньший значащий разряд писать 1,2,3 соответственно тому какая это часть (например, `34.000001`). Тут вас ограничивает сторонний софт который с этими STL должен будет тоже работать.